# forEach not executing the code properly. Got the same console.log message

Tags: javascript

The first `console.log` is supposed to display "Found Droids!" and the second is supposed to display "Not Found", but I get the same "Not Found" message for both. Not sure how to utilize `forEach` in this case.

```js
function droids(arr) {
  let result = '';
  if (arr.forEach === "Droids") {
    result = "Found Droid!"
  } else {
    result = "Droid Not Found"
  }
  return result;
}

const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"]
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"]
console.log(droids(starWars))
console.log(droids(thrones))
```

Comment: `arr.forEach === "Droids"`? What is this comparison supposed to achieve? `forEach` is a function, not a "Droids"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Given that I saw one of your previous questions before it was deleted, two things.  #1) `forEach` is not a `for loop`.  So if your instructor explicitly wanted you to use a for loop, your answer is going to fail.  #2) A forEach is not going to stop processing once it finds what it is looking for.  So if you set it to the true case for element 3, and element 4 doesn't match, your if logic is going to mark it as not found, even though it was previously found.

Comment: the proper syntax for "forEach" is `arr.forEach(callback(currentValue [, index [, array]])[, thisArg])` still i dont understand droid their

Answer (score 1):

you are using forEach wrong . forEach function is to loop through an array. you should use find to do this . something like this

```
function droids(arr) {
    let result = '';
        if ( arr.find(item => item === "Droids") ){
            result = "Found Droid!"
        } else {
            result = "Droid Not Found"
        }  
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a different function `arr.includes`

Like so

```js
function findItem(arr, value) {
  let result = '';
  if (arr.includes(value)) {
    result = `Found ${value}!`
  } else {
    result = `${value} Not Found`
  }
  return result;
}

const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"]
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"]

// Pass in the array into `findItem` and then the value
console.log(findItem(starWars, "Droids"))
console.log(findItem(thrones, "Droids"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to use the `forEach()` method, you could use this function that returns true if it finds the string `"Droids"`. I would, personally, use a conventional `for` loop in order to stop the loop once the string has been found. If you want to stop the forEach once the string is found, you will have to throw an exception.

```
function findDroids(array) {
    let flag = false;
    array.forEach(element => {
        if (element == "droids") flag = true; 
    });
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach is wrong here. Below is the simplified answer. You can use **indexOf** instead of **find**

```
function droids(arr) { 
        return  arr.indexOf("Droids") !== -1 ? "Found Droid!" :"Droid Not Found";
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your are not forced to use foreeach her is a simple answer

```
const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"] 
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"]
function droids(arr) {
  let result = '';
  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if (arr[i]==="Droids")
        {
        result = "Found Droid!";
        } else
        {result = "Droid Not Found"}  

 }
    return result;
```

}

```
console.log(droids(starWars)) 
console.log(droids(thrones))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf or ES6 feature some function as below.

**array.IndexOf:**

```
function droids(arr) { 
 return arr.indexOf("Droids") !== -1 ? "Found Droid!" :"Droid Not Found"; 
}
```

**array.some:**

```
    function droids(arr) { 
        return arr.some(x => x === "Droids") ? "Found Droid!" :"Droid Not Found"; 
   }
```

The `some` function executes the callback function once for each element in the array until it finds the one where the callback function returns a true. The some() method immediately returns true and doesn’t evaluate the remaining elements.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findWord(arr, word) {
  return arr.indexOf(word) !== -1 ? true : false;
}

const array = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"] 

var res = findWord(array, 'Droids')
console.log(res)
```